# Doomsday application - How do I delete it?

Tags: software-uninstall

I downloaded it from their website (dengine.net) and want to delete it, so I went to the Ubuntu Software Center and went to "installed" and it was not under there!

I tried dragging the application to the trash (Mac-style) and THAT didn't work!

Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: If my answer worked out for you please mark it as the accepted answer which helps everyone out. Thanks! :) Let me know if you have any more issues with it.

Answer (score 3):

Copy and paste or type this into your terminal and it should work for you:

```
sudo apt-get remove doomsday doomsday-common doomsday-data fluid-soundfont-gm freedoom libassimp3v5 libfluidsynth1 libmad0 libminizip1 libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 musescore-soundfont-gm timgm6mb-soundfont
```

That looks like all the packages related to it!

Also, to find out what packages on which a certain package depends, you can use the command

```
apt-cache depends packagename
```

which will list all dependencies for `packagename`, so

```
apt-cache depends doomsday
```

will list all the packages associated with `doomsday`.

Comment: Can't you just use `sudo apt-get purge doomsday`, and then `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: Sure. Either way will work, but `autoremove` is slightly less predictable than explicit statement of packages to be removed. If `autoremove` hasn't been run in a while, also there can be the issue of a ton of packages being removed and that can be daunting as well as potentially harmful, depending on what packages have been manually installed, on and on. And why not be specific when we can be? :)